# How I can disable an input type file control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a file upload control in my page added as below,

```
<input id="RCFileUpload" title="Upload" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="RCFileUpload" size="36" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
```

In a particular case, I need to disable this control. I have written below code for that.

```
If String.Compare(sStep, "SFOUND", True) = 0 Then
                    RCFileUpload.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly")
                End If
```

I am still able to open a dialog when I click on the control. How can I disable it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.disabled(v=vs.110).aspx

```
If String.Compare(sStep, "SFOUND", True) = 0 Then
  RCFileUpload.Disabled = True
End If
```

Comment: This still allows me to upload files

Comment: make sure that the statement under `if` condition executes

Comment: Yes the if condition executes, other controls in it are getting disabled except file upload